# Native Javascript querySelectorAll() with multiple/many pseudo selectors/matches

Tags: javascript, string-matching, selectors-api

How can I place many pseudo selectors inside the native Javascript querySelectorAll()?

Example: I want to search for an element with an id that starts with [id^=starting]  and ends with [id$=ending].
(Couldn't find existing question so making my own and answering it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Native Javascript this would be the code:

`document.querySelectorAll('[id^=starting][id$=ending]');`

or

`document.querySelectorAll('[id^='+startingString+'][id$='+endingString+']');`

This will get an element which starts with the specified string AND ends with the specified string.

Edit: And to do an "OR", put a space between them:

`document.querySelectorAll('[id^=starting] [id$=ending]');`

Comment: Note: There **shouldn't** be a space between `[id^=starting]` and  `[id$=ending]` if you are looking to match both on the same element.

Comment: Ah I see ... makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If you need to query for the elements starting with a string or with another string, you have to use the following structure:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id ^= "startingString-"], [id ^= "anotherStartingString-"]')
```