# How to get outermost parent node of inner child in plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I got stuck in a problem, I wish to write a script that can show all the div ids of an inner div, for example:

```
<body id="bd">
<div id="canvas">
    <div id="nd1">
        <div>
            My text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="nd2">
        <div id="hd">Some Text</div>
    <div>
<div>
```

What I want is suppose when I click on div with no ID defined inside "nd1", I should get its parent div (i.e. nd1), and the outermost parent, kind of thing I want.

Comment: Can I get all div ids in an array ?

Comment: the divs that are surrounding the div with no id(i.e. My text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
var allChildNodes = document.querySelectorAll("#nd1 div");
nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(allChildNodes ,0); 
nodes.forEach(function(node){ 
   node.addEventListener("click", function(){
     console.log("Outer parent" + node.parentNode.outerHTML);
     console.log("Outermost parent" + node.parentNode.parentNode.outerHTML);
   });
});
```

To get the array of parent divs

```
var allChildNodes = document.querySelectorAll("#nd1 div");
nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(allChildNodes ,0); 
nodes.forEach(function(node){ 
   node.addEventListener("click", function(){
     var parentDivs = [];
     while( !node.parentNode )
     {
        parentDivs.push(node.parentNode);
        node = node.parentNode;
     }
     console.log("parents" + parentDivs);
   });
});
```

For matching multiple divs starting from a specific string

```
var allChildNodes = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='nd'] div");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but inside querySelector, I want all nd's like nd1, nd2, nd3... they all are dynamic ids

Comment: @SiddharthaAgrawal that depends on how and when you bind this click handler.

Comment: and suppose If I want to select all nd, for example nd1, nd2, nd3... ? what should I write in query selector

Comment: @SiddharthaAgrawal 1document.querySelectorAll("[id='nd'] div");`

Comment: @SiddharthaAgrawal sorry missed the carret character `document.querySelectorAll("[id^='nd'] div");` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728600/native-javascript-queryselectorall-with-multiple-many-pseudo-selectors-matches

Comment: have you worked on website builder kind of project, like weebly ?

Comment: Glad to help. Worked on weebly long tiime ago, why?

Comment: Actually I've been assigned a project to develop website builder, but I dont know where to start from... so I will be very much thankful if you provide a path, a little help to proceed in a certain direction

Comment: Website builder is a big project. It will help you if you can list down what features you want to provide the end-user and then get started on the simplest one of those.

Comment: @SiddharthaAgrawal architecting and desigining a website builder is quite a big task and cannot be discussed in few comments. Best I can do is share some links of open-source website builders with you http://www.smallbusinesscomputing.com/slideshows/5-best-and-easy-open-source-website-builders.html